# How to extract data in encoded format from API response using Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, decode

I'm facing issue getting data from api response in flutter.

I've used the http to call the api and get the api response as well.
but not able to get the compressed data from api response.

Here is my api call code..

```
 http://14.xx.xx.xxx:9090/xyz/login
```

Here is api response object..

```
{
   "responseDynamic": "H4sIAAAAA  ....   02owNAAA",
   "responseCode": 200,
   "responseMessage": "User created",
}
```

I've to get data from responseDynamic which is in encoded format (include jsonObject and JsonList)

This is output on my console..

```
 url :http://14.xx.xx.xxx:9090/xyz/login
 Message : User created
 Response Dynamic : H4sIAAAAA  ....   02owNAAA
```

can anyone suggest me how I can get data from the "responseDynamic" key which is in encoded format.

This is the json of responseDynamic

```
{
    "User": {
        "UserDisplayName": "user_123",
        "AppAccessTypeID": 503,
        "ProfileName": "Profile 1"
    },
    "Store": [{
        "CompanyName": "ASD  Ltd",
        "SessionTime": 60,
        "DateShort": "dd-MM-yyyy",
        "DateLong": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "CompanyCountryMasterID": 1001,
        "CountryName": "India",
        "ContactPersonName": "SDF",
        "PrimaryTelNumber": "456465465",
        "PAN": "",
        "GSTIN": ""
    }],
    "Session": {
        "SessionID": 368,
        "ValidFrom": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ValidTo": "2023-05-30T13:03:25"
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like your responseDynamic is gzip compressed and base64 encoded. In this case, you'll need to decode the base64 string and decompress the gzip to get the original JSON string.